# Who is David? And why is he using the Android Stack Exchange client?

Tags: discussion, android-app, advertising

[image]

I've actually heard this asked a few times on chat, and I'm downright curious - Who is this David, and why is his use of the SE Android app important?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146719/david-fullerton

Comment: That would be plausible, yes!

Comment: I can't tell if he's doing a 'yes' fist-pump in a "SE ANDROID APP IS AMAZING" way, or if he's threatening to punch me if i don't use it myself.

Comment: Neither can I! Its a great app, and you shouldn't need to be threatened with a facepunch to use it!

Comment: I had gloves like that.. in the 80's (sorry Dave :P)

Comment: Probably should have used a power glove instead.

Comment: @JonW Why not both?

Comment: @JonW I'm sure he loves punching people: [StackExchange - Our Team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) - [David](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/team/David%20Fullerton.gif)

Comment: For the record, those gloves were a gift from Jeff Atwood back in the early days. It was part of a larger package that included every Rock Band game ever made, a drum set and stool, studded leather gloves, and a cowbell with the anarchy symbol on it. We eventually stopped playing Rock Band, but I kept the gloves...

Comment: [Here's a blank.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EW9tq.png)  You all know what to do.

Comment: It took me awhile to realize that this ad was for a StackExchange app, since it doesn't actually mention the name StackExchange.  And David's name is featured more prominently than that of the product being advertised, yet I had no idea who he was.  Maybe he should take that fist and go punch the VP of Marketing.  :-)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- David was the Vice President of Engineering for Stack Exchange, Inc. Despite the name, this does *not* mean he is responsible for all engineering [vices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice) - it just means he directs all development work.
- Unlike many of you poor, lost souls, David is proud to use something other than an iPhone.
- As you can see from the picture, David is a very angry man.
- David once had a desk that responded to his voice commands. Does *your* desk raise or lower itself in response to your utterances? I didn't think so.
- A radioactive spider once bit David. Now it puts on a costume and pretends to be a Vice President. Unfortunately, it didn't read my clarification regarding the use of the word "vice" above - so be *very* careful if you ever encounter a spider wearing a hoodie.

The above are all of the *primary* reasons, but it all may make a smidge more sense (well, not really) to those familiar with the "[Lucas uses Venmo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140217080257/http://lucasusesvenmo.com/)" campaign that no one understands which is all over the NYC Subway system:

[image]

Comment: this is starting to sound like a Skeet-ism

Comment: If David and Jon Skeet got in a fight, who would win?

Comment: What's most weird about this answer is the link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice, it's almost as though it's expected this site is so full of moral people, who are so unaware of vice that they need it explained to them... but that can't be true :-).

Comment: +1 just for that second bullet point alone.

Comment: I also wonder what poor, lost soul is going to be the one featured in the iOS app when it is released some day.

Comment: Or the windows phone app. You're going to hope you have one of the two people who use it working for SE ;).

Comment: What are some engineering vices? Is there a list?

Comment: Ask on Server Fault, @Pekka. They're the ones with the order page for those 55-gallon drums of lube bookmarked.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek those are just lost souls... those phones are much cheaper.

Comment: @MichaelT Neither. Chuck Norris would win. Even though he isn't there.

Comment: There is a use for [55-gallon drums of lube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTTkNLF5tUQ), though you may prefer not to know it.

Comment: +1 for iPhone users being poor, lost souls ;)