# Does anybody actually like the SE android app ad?

Tags: discussion, android-app, advertising

[image: SE Android App Ad featuring David]

Does anybody actually like this add? If it had voting buttons (where have these gone to by the way?) I would have downvoted it, and I only very rarely downvote anything.

I suppose the intention is to convey power, but everytime I see this add, I cringe. It makes me feel attacked rather than empowered or invited.

Just my opinion of course, so I am curious to know whether there are people that do like this ad and why.

Comment: He obviously has good teeth.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Good ads exist too. It doesn't happen often, but once in a while there's an ad that I enjoy seeing/hearing.

Comment: [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221239/who-is-david-and-why-is-he-using-the-android-stack-exchange-client) and see if you like the ad in the end.

Comment: *If it had voting buttons (where have these gone to by the way?)* - Are we supposed to consider this question to vote for the ad? An upvote for yes, I like the ad and downvote for no, its an eyesore?

Comment: I like some of SE Android ads, too bad (or good?) I don't see it often due to my reps. Well, honestly, this is the first time I see *this* ad.

Comment: I like that ad because *David is proud to use something other than an iPhone.*

Comment: @Kedarnath, maybe the ad could be improved with iPhone debris falling out of his fist.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and for iPhone app ad we have another [David](http://stackexchange.com/users/2879326/david)

Comment: @RJ No. Adds on the SE network had voting buttons at one time or another. IIRC these were to allow SE to get a feel for which adds were considered "on topic" or whatever. And possibly they were related to the free adds for open source project. Don't see them anymore.

Comment: @AndrewT. Didn't even know there were others. Somehow I get this one all the time :(

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: that would at least give some direction to his anger :)

Comment: @Antony: I saw that. Interesting but doesn't make me like it.

Comment: Dat image... what. the. actual. fk.