# Was the iOS app officially launched?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

The title says it all, was the iOS app officially launched?

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231190/launch-ios-app-from-sites) has a [link to the store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) for the app.

However, neither the [alpha announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app) nor the [beta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta) mention the official availability of the app.  The last update from a [SE peep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136973/ben-collins) was from 5/1/2014:

> As of today, the app is submitted for review. A great big thanks to
>   all our alpha testers! Your feedback has been invaluable and has truly
>   helped us make the app much better than it would have been without
>   you.

Inquiring minds want to know, and the paranoid among us always double check apps that use login credentials.

Comment: Developers can submit an app to the app store and set an availability date in the future. As long as they keep bumping up the availability date, it could be approved and "on the store" for months yet not actually available to end users. I'm fairly certain we haven't missed the announcement that the availability date has passed. That being said, it's live on the app store, so I'll make an answer to that effect.

Comment: From Kasea [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2029042#2029042): @mhlester :) Went live around 8 PM last night. Going to do the blog post and what not for it soon, I'm actually actively mid-writing the blog post right now.

Comment: I was hesitant to mention it at all before it was official, but he said go ahead. You've taken it to a whole new level though :)

Comment: Well, just found it on the app store in my iPhone so yeah, looks like it's official.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It soft-launched Tuesday. We're watching it to make sure nothing is horribly broken before doing the official launch.

In the meantime, go ahead and [download in the App Store now](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8), and consider giving us a nice review!

Comment: What's the reasoning for waiting until next week?

Comment: @mhlester Two reasons: 1) make sure nothing is terribly broken, 2) announce at the beginning of a week instead of the end to get more attention.

Comment: cool thanks. that answers my followup question too of why the release wasn't held back waiting for the announcement

Comment: have you done your ios app [banner ad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221239/who-is-david-and-why-is-he-using-the-android-stack-exchange-client) photo shoot yet? ;)

Comment: @mhlester I'm not entirely sure where Jin got that image from, but I do still have the gloves...

Comment: @mhlester Shog9's answer says "David is proud to use something other than an iPhone", so using his photo to promote iOS app would be a bit deceptive.

Comment: ...and then we decided to launch on a Thursday, so apparently I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: [Someone](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/464485377622147073) wanted to scoop the marketing department...

Answer (score 0):

Yes - The US app store has the official stack exchange app at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8

I can confirm that the app store version (1.0.0) of the app is just about identical to the last alpha I tested (v 1.0.0.67), but you can wait for someone that works for SE to confirm this if you want to be extra careful.