# Why does the iOS app say alpha?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Why does the iOS app (in the help section) say it's an alpha version?

Is this a bug or did you actually release an alpha version of the app on the App Store?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231233/was-the-ios-app-officially-launched

Comment: Ken, yes I saw that post but it doesn't help me. I downloaded Stackexchange from the App Store and was not part of or aware of any alpha/Vera program. I am confused as to why it still says alpha in the version that was released on the App Store

Comment: There was an extended alpha version, and then (as the linked post says), the beta version was uploaded for review for the App Store (in the quoted text on that linked post dated 5/1/2014). I'm not sure how that does not help you - the answer is "Yes, there was an alpha version on the App Store, and a beta version was uploaded for review for the App Store." Therefore, it says "alpha" because it's the "alpha" version that was released on the App Store. :-)

Comment: Fine. It just doesn't seem like you should release an alpha product on the store. Or at least not call it that.

Comment: It was announced here that the alpha was published, in order to allow people to **get it** for the alpha test. How else would you expect them to get it out to a large number of people for testing? Magic? Telling people it's alpha helps explain why they're finding problems, and clearly indicates it's not the final (release) version.

Comment: They intended to release as beta on the app store. I think they just named it wrong. [Stack Exchange iOS app nearing beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta)

Comment: @KenWhite probably worthwhile to actually write that up as an answer

Comment: I understand calling it an alpha product here so people can find it. Just not in the final 1.0 version that is released on the store. If you want to distribute a unreleased version there is Testflight and Hockeyapp (or whatever) and I totally understand why it would be called alpha there just not on the store.

Comment: This is what I was looking for @mhlester. All I was trying to do was let them know they made a mistake so they could fix it in the next version.

Comment: @user260219: There is no "final 1.0 version" yet. The *beta* (which is the step of testing prior to a release version) is currently being reviewed by Apple. What term would you prefer to use for "the version released to the public for testing prior to the actual beta that is closer to the version we want to release"? "Alpha" seems considerably shorter to me. :-)

Comment: If it's currently being reviewed by the Apple team how is it already live for the public to download?

Comment: @Ken, nothing is being reviewed by apple. it's already been reviewed and is released

Comment: @mhlester: Ah, I don't see that announcement here. (I use the Android version, so my knowledge of the iOS version is only what I read here.) Thanks.

Comment: @psubsee2003: :-) I don't have the iOS version, so I'm basing all that on what I see here in announcements. I'm waiting for someone to jump in here and tell me I'm all wrong about the alpha, just as mhlester did about the beta still being in review. :-)

Comment: The alpha was closed (like the testflight OP alluded to, but not). Beta is public, and what's on the app store. See the post I linked to

Comment: @mhlester: The one I linked in the very first comment here is more recent, and contains updated information as of 5/1/14 (the same as the one you linked). I would have used the one you linked if I'd seen it first. Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we never think about that screen and forgot to update it. This will be fixed in an upcoming release. I believe we're calling 1.x a public beta.