# Why do beta sites typically launch on Tuesday?

Tags: discussion, area-51, private-beta

In an answer on Area 51, Robert Cartaino mentions that [beta sites usually launch on a Tuesday.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26235/84544) A cursory review of beta site history seems to show that, somewhat surprisingly, this is actually true.

I've, uh, gotta wonder why? I'm honestly just curious. It's probably some boring internal reason, admittedly, but it's going to itch at me forever if I don't know why.

Comment: Traditional Taco Tuesday - the taco is a reward for launching a site

Comment: @Doc I like this explanation.

Comment: I would assume it's enough that it's a) not Monday and b) gives maximum time before the weekend to deal with breakages and general chaos.

Comment: asides from the regular everyday chaos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not limited to launching beta sites.

Looks like many major changes take place on Tuesday. Few more  examples:

- [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)
- [Launch of the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231249/152859)
- [Updating version of jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4-please-report-related-bugs-here)

As for why, I assume because it gives the team time to prepare for whole day (Monday), then time to fix bugs for the rest of the week. Doing it before Tuesday, meaning Monday, will not give enough time for last sanity checks, and after Tuesday it won't give enough time to fix bugs resulting from the change.

In case of private beta launch, just replace "fix bugs" above with "helping the site in its first steps".

Worth to mention that it's not even limited to Stack Exchange, e.g.

- [Americans vote on Tuesday](http://www.whytuesday.org/answer/)
- [Android was introduced in Tuesday](http://www.historyofinformation.com/expanded.php?id=3000)
- [Patch Tuesday, Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday)

Comment: Also, Monday holidays are more common than Tuesday holidays, so some weeks would become unavailable for launches unless SE were to change its process in those cases.

Comment: Also participation during weekdays is typically much higher than in the weekends on almost all sites (you'd think people have more time in the weekend, so make of that what you will). Launching early in the week is probably better, since launching it on a Thursday/Friday may result in a "dud start" (I don't know if this is an actual reason for the Tuesday launches though).

Comment: Don't forget [Patch Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday) and so far nobody denied [they actually use that deploy route](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6027025#6027025) ....